# table-layout:fixed auto width

Tags: css, word-wrap, tablelayout

I have a code as displayed in here : http://jsfiddle.net/db4XL/
The table-layout:fixed seems to divide the child elements into two 50% width.
Is there any posible way to make the div.number width is auto?
Please look at this image for what I want to achieve :

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Looks like tabular data to me, use a table!

Comment: @MoinZaman It is a part of complex application that is not working with table markup, so I use div instead

Comment: What do you mean by "auto?" Is it a dynamic width? You can use percentages or use a specific width.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks yes,I meant dynamic width. I can't use percentage or a fix width

Comment: Then unless you want a Javascript solution, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. If you want the table cells to resize to the content so the left cell is splitted at approx 30% then you'll **have** to use percentages. Here's a working jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/db4XL/7/

What you are asking for just isn't possible. The standard behaviour for tables using the auto property on all cells is to divide it equally.